# How to access rectangles, fit type, zoom, page number from outlines/bookmark of pdf in iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am using iText 7.

I am trying to access properties like (rectangle, fit type, zoom, page number) of the PDF bookmarks using iText.

I followed this hierarchy -> `PdfDocument` -> `GetOutlines(true)` -> this gives each bookmark/outline.
I have looped through each bookmark but I could not access the view destination properties that should contain rectangles, fit type, zoom and page number.

I know when creating a new book mark I have used `PdfExplicitDestination.CreateXYZ` but I could not access the view destinations from the pdf document.

Comment: I found some code but still could not able to access rectangles

Comment: var array = ((PdfArray)bmk.GetDestination().GetPdfObject());

     for (int i = 0; i < array.Size(); i++)
     {
      Console.WriteLine(array.Get(i).ToString() + "/n");
      if (PdfName.Fit.Equals(array.Get(i)))
      {
       var k = array.Get(i).ToString();
      }
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you can retrieve from the `PdfDestination` mostly is pretty raw PDF. Thus, the destination is not in the format you want but either a name, a byte string, or an array. The former two options are named destinations, i.e. you have to lookup the destination array in the **Dests** names tree.

```
IDictionary<String, PdfObject> names = document.GetCatalog().GetNameTree(PdfName.Dests).GetNames();

[...]
if ([... some PdfOutline instance ...].GetDestination() is PdfDestination destination)
{
    PdfObject destObject = destination.GetPdfObject();
    if (destObject is PdfString str)
    {
        destObject = names[str.ToUnicodeString()];
    }
    else if (destObject is PdfName nam)
    {
        destObject = names[nam.GetValue()];
    }
```

Now you should have a `PdfArray` and can inspect its values. The page dictionary is the first object in it, so

```
    if (destObject is PdfArray arr)
    {
        if (arr.Get(0) is PdfDictionary pageDict)
        {
            int pageNumber = document.GetPageNumber(pageDict);
            [...]
        }
        [... inspect remaining array entries ...]
    }
}
```

There actually are a number of possible forms of this array to consider when inspecting remaining array entries:

> **[*page* /XYZ *left top zoom*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with the coordinates (*left, top*) positioned at the upper-left corner of the window and the contents of the page magnified by the factor zoom. A null value for any of the parameters *left, top,* or *zoom* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged. A *zoom* value of 0 has the same meaning as a null value.
>
> **[*page* /Fit]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with its contents magnified just enough to fit the entire page within the window both horizontally and vertically. If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, use the smaller of the two, centring the page within the window in the other dimension.
>
> **[*page* /FitH *top*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with the vertical coordinate *top* positioned at the top edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire width of the page within the window. A null value for *top* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> **[*page* /FitV *left*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with the horizontal coordinate *left* positioned at the left edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire height of the page within the window. A null value for *left* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> **[*page* /FitR *left bottom right top*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with its contents magnified just enough to fit the rectangle specified by the coordinates *left, bottom, right,* and *top* entirely within the window both horizontally and vertically. If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, use the smaller of the two, centring the rectangle within the window in the other dimension.
>
> **[*page* /FitB]**
>   (PDF 1.1) Display the page designated by *page*, with its contents magnified just enough to fit its bounding box entirely within the window both horizontally and vertically. If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, use the smaller of the two, centring the bounding box within the window in the other dimension.
>
> **[*page* /FitBH *top*]**
>   (PDF 1.1) Display the page designated by *page*, with the vertical coordinate *top* positioned at the top edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire width of its bounding box within the window. A null value for *top* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> **[*page* /FitBV *left*]**
>   (PDF 1.1) Display the page designated by *page*, with the horizontal coordinate *left* positioned at the left edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire height of its bounding box within the window. A null value for *left* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 149 — Destination syntax)*